# jQuery resize only working partially

Tags: jquery, window-resize, jquery-resizable

OK, first off, I am NOT really familiar with javascript, so please forgive if this seems a really dumb question...

Here's my code to dynamically resize header items depending on **window height** (logo, title) and navigation bar depending on **width of dynamically sized logo & title**:

```
function titlesize (){
  var winsize = {
    width: document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth || document.body.offsetWidth,
    height: document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight || document.body.offsetHeight
  };

  var titlefont = $(".title");
  var logo= $(".logo");
  var logow = winsize.height * 0.2;
  var logoh = winsize.height * 0.15;
  var titlefontsize = winsize.height * 0.03;
  var titlew = titlefontsize * 7;

  if (winsize.height > 580) {
    logo.css({width: logow, height: logoh});
    titlefont.css('font-size', function(){return (titlefontsize);});
    titlefont.css('width', function(){return (titlew);});
  }
  else {
    var logow = "150";
    var logoh = "100";
    var titlew = "122.5";
    logo.css({width: logow, height: logoh});
    titlefont.css({'font-size': "17.5px", width: titlew});
  }

  if ((winsize.width > 480) && ((winsize.width * 0.9) < (logow + titlew + 420))) {
    $("nav").css({float: "left"});
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {titlesize(); $(window).resize(titlesize);$(window).load(titlesize);});
```

Explained: I have a title logo and text dynamically resized according to **window height** rather than the usual width, so that the overall header does not take too much of the screen (especially on mobile devices in landscape).

Navigation bar will then be placed: top right if there is enough space (default), or below header (float:left).

The problem is: Window resizing does resize logo and text just fine, but not the nav bar. That does only react on reload, not on resize. Is there any reason why?

I suspect it is because of the dependency of those dynamic variables deriving from the first if else statement. I'm pretty sure there is a simple solution, but what?

Thanks for any help.

PS: tried to make a jsfiddle, but it gives me POST error (no idea why, there is no form submit or anything like that)

**EDIT & SOLUTION**

Figured out why it did not work: simply made a mistake in the var declarations

I set in the `else` part of the function vars *logow* and *titlew* to fixed values in **quotes**, thus js took them as text rather than numbers. Hence, the calculation for the nav just messed up. Declaring those vars as numbers (`var logow = 150;`) did the trick.

Thanks nevertheless for your help and the great hint at media query with heights!

Comment: cant you use media queries to do resizing...

Comment: No, because media queries depend on window WIDTH while my function/elements resize depending on window HEIGHT. I do, however, use media query in the winsize.width > 480 in the nav part for small screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DominicaJune is right. You can use media queries for height:

http://trentwalton.com/2012/01/11/vertical-media-queries-wide-sites/

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in a very interesting direction! I can only repeat what Ch. Meeks replied to the mentioned post: "I have to humbly admit that I wasn’t even aware that you could use media-queries for screen heights. With so much focus on screen widths, that idea completely passed me by." That said, it still does not really help me, because with media-query I can only set certain fixed thresholds, whereas I want to resize my elements to any given screen height and width. Thus: I will go give Jish's solution a go and see if that does the trick for me. +1 from me nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

You're throwing your resize in document ready.
If you have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//some code
});

$(window).resize(function(){
//your resize code
});
```

It should work all the time. Although media queries look a lot simpler.

Comment: On closer look, that was what I already had in my last line: `$(document).ready(function() {titlesize(); $(window).resize(titlesize);$(window).load(titlesize);});`

Comment: No, your function
`$(document).ready(function() {` opens, then closes after `$(window).load(titlesize);`
Put `$(window).resize` outside of $(document).ready

Comment: thanks for the clarification! As mentioned at the very top: I'm a js novice. Changed it, and with my corrected calculation it works now like a charm. Cheers.